# Android remote process: messenger vs aidl? Which is better?

Tags: android, android-service

I currently have a remote service that communicates constantly with an activity on the same app.

I need to send messages in and out extensively at some times.  Which method of messaging is better, faster, and battery friendly? Using messages or aidl interface?

As of now I'm using aidl interface but for some reason I think there is a lot of overhead specially when attaching listeners...

Any feedback greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does your service have to be in a remote process? Also, why does it have to be run continuously?

Comment: Well, my app is a multimedia audio application that needs to run in the background which requires a lot of resources: memory.  Having this in the same process as my activities would most likely bring issues to reaching the limit of resource usage per process.  Also, the benefits are, if your UI crashes for some reason your service doesn't...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I currently have a remote service that communicates constantly with an activity on the same app.

A remote services is generally not a good idea.

> Well, my app is a multimedia audio application that needs to run in the background which requires a lot of resources: memory. Having this in the same process as my activities would most likely bring issues to reaching the limit of resource usage per process.

Then use less memory. A audio player should not need to exceed the per-process RAM limits, even with activities.

> Also, the benefits are, if your UI crashes for some reason your service doesn't.

This is not a particularly good reason for wasting device RAM and CPU time. That's a fine approach for a server, less so for an embedded system.

> Which method of messaging is better, faster, and battery friendly? Using messages or aidl interface?

They should be fairly comparable. IPC considerations should swamp most other effects. For example, quoting myself from one of my books:

> For example, in the CPU-Java/AIDLOverhead directory of the book's source
>   code, you will find a pair of projects implementing the same do-nothing
>   method in equivalent services. One uses AIDL and is bound to remotely
>   from a separate client application; the other is a local service in the client
>   application itself. The client then calls the do-nothing method 1 million
>   times for each of the two services. On average, on a Samsung Galaxy Tab
>   10.1, 1 million calls takes around 170 seconds for the remote service, while it
>   takes around 170 milliseconds for the local service. Hence, the overhead of
>   an individual remote method invocation is small (~170 microseconds), but
>   doing lots of them in a loop, or as the user flings a ListView, might become
>   noticeable.

That being said, if you are concerned about the overhead (yet insist on the remote service), you are probably better served trying both and using logging to determine if there is a clear winner.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  The memory usage has been highly optimized but still I need to use a quantity than on some older phones it is not possible.  The reason is a lot of data processing going on.  Something I did not mention is that having the service and activity running on the same process creates the UI to become sluggish and I noticed with a remote service things work a lot smoother.  In regards to your last quote thanks for the info I'll run a few test cases to determine which is better.

Comment: quote: "A remote services is generally not a good idea."
 if it is not good idea, should he use just local service instead?